# How can I replace the use of a perl module with a call to an external program?

Tags: perl, filter, perl-module, template-toolkit

Here's what I'm starting with

```
#$Id: MultiMarkdown.pm 4103 2009-03-02 20:41:50Z andrew $

package Template::Plugin::MultiMarkdown;

use strict;
use base qw (Template::Plugin::Filter);

use Text::MultiMarkdown;

our $VERSION = 0.03;

sub init {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{_DYNAMIC} = 1;
    $self->install_filter($self->{_ARGS}->[0] || 'multimarkdown');
    return $self;
}

sub filter {
    my ($self, $text, $args, $config) = @_;
    my $m = Text::MultiMarkdown->new(%{$config || {}});
    return $m->markdown($text);
}

1;
```

---

I want to change the reference to the Perl moudule [`Text::MultiMarkdown`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::MultiMarkdown) 
to use an executable `/usr/local/bin/multimarkdown`

I think I need to change:

```
use Text::MultiMarkdown;
```

To

```
use IPC::run3
```

and then the `my $m` line involves a call to `run3`, but then I'm lost.

I have found some mentions of how to write a filter on both the Template Toolkit mailing list, and on Perl Monks, but in both cases the answer assumes that I know something that I don't and it goes right over my head, hence the request here.

I asked a similar question earlier, but the answer given didn't seem to apply to using an external program.

Comment: I'm not sure to get you right but if it's a static call to the file (not to be dynamically changed based on something you compute) then you should be able to call something like this: use '/usr/local/bin/multimarkdown';

Comment: Use, I think, will attempt to parse whatever the argument is as a perl script.  See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html  I can't see that working.

Comment: I hope you have a good reason? It seems to be a very bad idea to replace a simple Perl procedure call with some code that needs to create one and possibly two new processes and arrange to pass the parameters and receive the result. Does your `multimarkdown` even accept simple text input, or does it require a file?

Comment: The simple reason is that the perl version of MMD hasn't been updated in years.  Fletcher Penny, the author, wrote the current version using a PEG grammar (I think that's the word).  It accepts input from stdin, writes output to stdout.  The existing version writes non-xhtml compliant code.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford: It's good to say stuff like that in your question. Very often a good answer is about discovering what the OP really needs and providing that instead of what they asked for. I guess you need *multimarkdown* and *markdown* won't do? Have you raised a bug report for `Text::MultiMarkdown`? Would it change your mind if I fixed it?

Comment: AFAIK Text::Multimarkdown is a reinvention of FP's several times ago version.  I think you would have to reverse engineer the syntax of FP's current version.  Backporting grammar + c code back to perl doesn't make a lot of sense.  In general for TT2, having a recipe to use an arbitrary well behaved program (reads from stdin, writes to stdout) as a filter in TT2 would be a win.  An even better win would be a TT2 Filter module that was called [% FILTER /usr/local/bin/whatever %]

Comment: I'm not a programmer.  I'm a tree farmer who hacks a bit of perl to maintain his website.  TT2 allows me to write markdown, not html.  TT2 and a week of learning some of it's scripting allowed me to create an automatic menu generating system.  Fletch will support HTML5 if it doesn't already.  This gives me more options for diagrams, and smarter pages.

Comment: The existing version of Text::Multimarkdown does not behave consistently with nested lists, does not treat <div> and <DIV> as equivalent wraps things that are html in <p> tags.

Comment: I have been using [cmark](https://github.com/jgm/cmark) via [CommonMark](https://metacpan.org/pod/CommonMark) and [Template::Plugin::CommonMark](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Plugin::CommonMark) in case it helps.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford: *"I'm not a programmer. I'm a tree farmer ... who hacks a bit of perl to maintain his website"* and *"The existing version of `Text::Multimarkdown` does not behave consistently"*. You must make up your mind whom you are. If you claim to have found a bug in Perl or its core modules then say so; otherwise Stack Overflow is not for you

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford: You have posted many comments without naming a recipient. They will go unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example of a filter that calls an external program ( `perl` ) to replace all occurences of "Hello" with "Bye". It uses [`IPC::Run3`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3):

```
package Template::Plugin::MultiMarkdown;
use strict;
use base qw (Template::Plugin::Filter);

use IPC::Run3;
our $VERSION = 0.03;

sub init {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{_DYNAMIC} = 1;
    $self->install_filter($self->{_ARGS}->[0] || 'multimarkdown');
    return $self;
}

sub filter {
    my ($self, $text, $args, $config) = @_;
    my $out;
    run3 ['perl', '-pE', 's/Hello/Bye/g'], \$text, \$out; 
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ideas and design are wrong. You mustn't extend the purview of any subclass beyond its parent. Overloading a method to use a system call is horrible.